# How to distinguish devices connected to same network from outside

Tags: java, networking, xmlhttprequest

I am developing a security web application in java. I have a requirement like this. If a user login multiple times with same credentials, but from the different location like different system(IP), different user agent(browser), then invalided the login. But my problem is If many devices connected by a common network then their all IP address are same.At this scenario how to distinguish the devices or login (may be user can use same user agent).
**I am using HttpServletRequest** .

Any help will be appreciated.